# I can't access HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript

I can't access HTMLCollection Type When I use getElementsByClassName.

I wanna get the length but I can't get that

```
var documentHeader = parent.document.all['header'];
var motionClass = documentHeader.getElementsByClassName('motion');
```

this is a result of motionClass

```
HTMLCollection []
 0: div.motion
 length: 1
 __proto__ : HTMLColletion
```

If I access length result is 0

How can I result This Issue?

Comment: Don't use `document.all`.

Comment: You're probably accessing it after the element no longer exists / matches.

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code including the CSS and HTML. And, be sure to show the location where you've embedded your script into the HTML.

Comment: I found why was not working.
iframe process before parent Document Loaded. I resolved Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a more modern approach - use `documentQuerySelectorAll()` to get the collection - this can then be iterated over to give each item - or can give the length of the collection.

```js
let motions = document.querySelectorAll('.motion');
console.log(motions.length); // gives 5
console.log(motions[2].textContent); // gives "3" - the text content of that element
```

```html
<div class='motion'>1</div>
<div class='motion'>2</div>
<div class='motion'>3</div>
<div class='motion'>4</div>
<div class='motion'>5</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: Here we execute the code safely when the DOM is ready. Ensure you are doing that.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let motionArray = document.getElementsByClassName('motion');
  console.log(motionArray.length);
});
```

```html
<div class='motion'>test</div>
<div class='motion'>test</div>
<div class='motion'>test</div>
<div class='motion'>test</div>
<div class='motion'>test</div>
<div class='motion'>test</div>
<div class='motion'>test</div>
```